# Matrix of linear operator in different bases [PMA Rudin]

Tags: operator-theory

> $\mathbf{9.35}\quad$ **Theorem** $\ \; $ *If $[A]$ and $[B]$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices, then $$\det([B][A])=\det[B]\det[A].$$*
>
> $\mathbf{9.36}\quad$ **Theorem** $\ \; $ *A linear operator $A$ on $R^n$ is invertible if and only if $\det[A]\neq 0$.*
>
> $\qquad\mathbf{9.37}\quad$ **Remark** $\ \; $ Suppose $\{\mathbf e_1,\ldots,\mathbf e_n\}$ and $\{\mathbf u_1,\ldots,\mathbf u_n\}$ are bases in $R^n$. Every linear operator $A$ on $R^n$ determines matrices $[A]$ and $[A]_U$, with entries $a_{ij}$ and $\alpha_{ij}$, given by $$A\mathbf e_j=\sum_i a_{ij}\mathbf e_i,\qquad\; A\mathbf{u}_j=\sum_i \alpha_{ij}\mathbf{u}_i.$$ If $\color{red}{\underset{\Rule{8.5em}{0.1em}{0.09em}}{\color{black}{\mathbf u_j=B\mathbf e_j=\sum b_{ij}\mathbf e_i}}}$, then $A\mathbf u_j$ is equal to $$\sum_k\alpha_{kj}B\mathbf{e}_k=\sum_k \alpha_{kj}\sum_i b_{ik}\mathbf{e}_i=\sum_i\left(\displaystyle\sum_k b_{ik}\alpha_{kj}\right)\mathbf e_i,$$ and also to $$AB\mathbf e_j=A\sum_k b_{kj}\mathbf e_k=\sum_i\left(\displaystyle\sum_k a_{ik}b_{kj}\right)\mathbf{e}_i.$$ Thus $\sum b_{ik}\alpha_{kj}=\sum a_{ik}b_{kj}$, or $$\tag{91} [B][A]_U=[A][B].$$ $\color{red}{\underset{\Rule{8.5em}{0.1em}{0.09em}}{{\color{black}{\text{Since $B$ is invertible,}}}}}$ $\det[B]\neq 0$. Hence $(91)$, combined with Theorem $9.35$, shows that $$\tag{92}\det[A]_U=\det[A].$$ $\qquad$ The determinant of the matrix of a linear operator does therefore not depend on the basis which is used to construct the matrix. *It is thus meaningful to speak of the determinant of a linear operator, without having any basis in mind.*

This excerpt from Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* and I have couple of questions.

1) What is $B$? He wrote that $\mathbf{u}_j=B\mathbf{e}_j=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{ij}\mathbf{e}_i$. I guess that $B$ is some  linear operator that translates each $\mathbf{e}_j$ to $\mathbf{u}_j$. Am I right? 
If yes why such operator exists?

2) Why $B$ is invertible? Why it's so obvious?

Can anyone answer to my questions please.

Comment: It would help to say which book by Rudin (and maybe which Rudin!) you are studying.  At a guess, $B$ is a linear mapping on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $[B]$ is a matrix that represents $B$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: @hardmath, 1) W. Rudin "Principles of Math/ Analysis" 2) I know that $B$ is linear mapping with matrix $[B]$. By the way, $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ and $\{u_1,\dots, u_n\}$ could be any bases not only standard basis.

Comment: You may be right, though often $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is used to denote the standard basis, and thus some other basis $U=\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ would be designated as the basis with respect to which $[B]_U$ represents $B$.  The notation is being marshalled here to be able to state and prove the proposition that the determinant of a matrix representing a linear operator is not dependent on the choice of basis.

Comment: @hardmath, I can't understand only two moments. 1) Why such $B$ exists? 2) Why $B$ is invertible? Can you help me with it?

Comment: I suspect that Rudin has introduced the principle that a linear operator is well-defined by its action on a basis of a vector space.  Thus, in order to define linear operator $B:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, we only need to say what $B$ does to each element of a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I crafted my answer assuming familiarity with this "action on a basis" principle.  If not, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically we have just one operator, namely $A$. This is the map that moves the points of our space $V:={\mathbb R}^n$ around. In order to deal with this $A$ in a computational way we have to choose a basis for $V$. At the outset we would use the standard basis $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ of ${\mathbb R}^n$, and with respect to this basis the operator $A$ assumes the matrix $[a_{ij}]$.

If we choose another basis $(u_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ then each $u_j$ is a linear combination of the $e_i$, hence $u_j=\sum_i b_{ij}e_i$ $\>(1\leq j\leq n)$ for a certain matrix $B$. Don't think of $B$ as an operator. It's just an $(n\times n)$-array of numbers encoding the numerical relations between the two sets of basis vectors.

Since in the same way each $e_i$ is a linear combination of the $u_k$ we have as well $e_i=\sum_k c_{ki} u_k$ $\>(1\leq i\leq n)$ for a certain matrix $C$. It is then easy to see that in fact $BC=I$, which proves that $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is a notational device, to be able to describe a change of basis operator $B$, by defining its action on the (standard?) basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$:

$$ Be_j = u_j, \;\; j=1,\ldots,n $$

Then we can related the matrix representation of any other linear operator $A$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard basis and the representation of the same operator with respect to (nonstandard) basis $U$.

The second part of the question asks why we know that $B$ is invertible.  This is because its action on one (ordered) basis gives the other ordered basis.  That is, the inverse of $B$ is exactly the linear operator whose action on a basis is as follows:

$$  (B^{-1})u_j = e_j, \;\; j = 1,\ldots,n $$

Since this definition of a linear operator by its "action on a basis" is well-defined, it remains only to verify that in fact $(B^{-1})$ composed with $B$ is the identity operator.

**Added:**

W. Rudin concisely treats the definition of linear operators, at least in finite dimensional spaces, through "action on a basis" in a couple of paragraphs at the top of page $207$ in PMA 3rd edition.

Assuming no familiarity of the "action on a basis" principle for defining (uniquely) a linear operator, we can write out just why this principle is justified in a particular case of change of basis.

That is, supposing $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ and $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ are bases, we can define a linear operator $B$ such that:

$$ Be_j = u_j, \;\; j=1,\ldots,n $$

by using the ability of basis elements to span a vector space, and the linear independence property to show uniqueness (well-definition).

So given any $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can express $v$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors $e_j$ in exactly one way:

$$ v = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j e_j $$

where the scalar coefficients $c_j$ are uniquely determined by $v$.

Now *define* $B:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so that:

$$ Bv = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j u_j $$

There are details to verify, that $B$ as thus defined is indeed a linear operator.  One way to visualize this is by identifying $B$ as acting by matrix multiplication on the "standard" coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, namely (treating input as column vectors):

$$ B \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & \dots & u_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} $$

where the multiplying matrix contains the ordered basis elements $u_j$ as columns.

Since $e_j$ in these coordinates is simply the column vector with a $1$ in the $j$th entry and zeros elsewhere, multiplying $e_j$ by that matrix picks out the $j$th column, namely $u_j$.  Thus $Be_j = u_j$, as promised.

Comment: What did you think about below proof of second part? If $Bx=By$ where $x=x_1e_1+\dots+x_ne_n$ and $y=y_1e_1+\dots+y_ne_n$. Then $B(x-y)=\sum\limits_{i} (x_i-y_i)Be_i=\sum\limits_{i} (x_i-y_i)u_i=0$. Hence $x_i=y_i$ since $\{u_1,\dots, u_n\}$ is a basis. Thus $B\in L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is injective. Hence $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @RFZ:  That's a good proof.  There are lots of equivalences for linear operators to be invertible, particularly in finite dimensional spaces, e.g. in finite dimensions injective is equivalent to invertible.  I like my proof only in that if we have two bases, the "change of basis" operator has an inverse that makes the change of basis going in the other direction.  One can verify the composition is the identity operator because it has a combined action of sending an ordered basis to itself.  This argument does not depend on finite dimensionality.

Comment: But your answer to my first answer seems to me little hard and I can't understand it :(

Comment: Okay, the first part of your Question seemed to be "what is $B$?" (which I think you understand) and "if yes, why such operator exists?"  You never said that "action on a basis" was covered in your studies, so let's tackle it in a different way.  I'll add a note about how the matrix that represents $B$ (the linear operator) in the standard basis, namely $[B]$, must exist.  Then $B$ is defined as multiplication (of standard coordinates) by $[B]$.